# Glitch in the set active and Input.touch in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have an app that spawns a model on user click, and when the user taps the model, a menu pops up.

When the user taps anywhere else except the canvas element, the menu closes.

But this is not working, when I press the canvas element, it detects the canvas element, but still, the menu closes.

Here is my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
        UpdatePlacementIndicator();
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 )//&& Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit hit;
            debugText.text = "touched";

            // Check if finger is over a UI element
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
            {
                Debug.Log("Touched the UI");
                debugText1.text = "Touched the UI";
                isui = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isui = false;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && (hit.transform.name != "Quad"))
                {
                    //debugText.text = hit.transform.name;
                    debugText.text = Input.touchCount.ToString();
                    if (IsSpawned)
                    {
                        debugText1.text = ColourImage.activeSelf.ToString();
                        ColourImage.SetActive(true);
                        //debugText.text = objectToPlace.name;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && !IsSpawned)
                    {
                        PlaceObject();
                        IsSpawned = true;
                        PlayerPrefs.SetString("type", "medium");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      ColourImage.SetActive(false);
                    }

                }
            }


        }

        //if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        //{
        //    PlaceObject();
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create "blocker" object which is behind your UI menu.

```
private GameObject CreateBlocker()
{
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("Blocker");
    RectTransform rectTransform = gameObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    rectTransform.SetParent(transformObjectBehindMenu, 
    false);
    rectTransform.anchorMin = (Vector2)Vector3.zero;
    rectTransform.anchorMax = (Vector2)Vector3.one;
    rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    Canvas canvas = gameObject.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.overrideSorting = true;
    canvas.sortingOrder += 1;
    gameObject.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<Image>().color = Color.clear;
    gameObject.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { 
    CloseMenu(); });
    return gameObject;
}
```

Call this method on your model click and you can navigate in menu and close when you click anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `GraphicRaycaster` to test if click events target UI elements.

This is a simple Demo to give the idea

```
public class Demo : MonoBehaviour
{

#pragma warning disable 0649
    [SerializeField] private EventSystem _eventSystem;
    [SerializeField] private GraphicRaycaster _graphicRaycaster;
#pragma warning restore 0649

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (TestClickEvent(Input.mousePosition))
            {
                Debug.Log("Clicked UI Element");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool TestClickEvent(Vector3 mousePos)
    {
        PointerEventData data = new PointerEventData(_eventSystem);
        data.position = mousePos;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        _graphicRaycaster.Raycast(data, results);
        if(results.Count > 0)
        {
            //You can loop through the results to test for a specific UI element
            return true;
        }       
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more information see the official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html)